# legal usage of is_transparent in regards partial keys

Tags: c++, c++14

If I have a `std::set<std::pair<A, B>, compare>` and wish to retrieve a range of values from the set where `element.first == some_a`, would it be regarded as correct and valid use of `is_transparent` to define the comparison function with

```
struct compare {
  using is_transparent = void;
  bool operator()(const std::pair<A,B> &l, const std::pair<A,B> &r) const {
    return l < r;
  }
  bool operator()(const std::pair<A,B> &l, const A& r) const {
    return l.first < r;
  }
  bool operator()(const A &l, const std::pair<A,B>& r) const {
    return l < r.first;
  }
};
```

and then use `lower_bound(some_a)` / `upper_bound(some_a)`?  Or would this be off-piste usage of the feature and undefined?

The motivation for this approach is that it is generic, and thus I do not have the necessary availability of a min B or successor A which would allow for other approaches such as `lower_bound(make_pair(some_a, min_b))` `lower_bound(make_pair(successor(some_a), min_b))`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. Note also that you can use `set::equal_range` - it's essentially `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` rolled into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [explicitly allows](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#8.sentence-1) “key” values that are related to the keys in the container in only one direction, so long as the partition that results is consistent with the container’s order.  In particular, `lower_bound` uses only one of your heterogeneous `operator()`s; `upper_bound` uses (only) the other.